# Java Programming, Statistical Methods

Tags: java, statistics

So I'm doing this code for a school project and my code keeps screwing up.  It happens in the fillRandomArray method and I get two errors, a misplaced construct on the while loop, and then an error telling me to remove the curly bracket enclosing the loop.  I basically want the loop to go through just those 4 statements and fill up the array with values with 3 standard deviations.  Then afterwards, I'll go off and subtract to create a pseudo-normal curve.

```
   import javax.swing.*;
   import java.util.*;
   import java.util.Arrays;
   public class statisticalModel
   {
    //Initates a place for the normal curve to be placed.
    static double Ho;
    //Real proportion of data statistic.
    static double Ha;
    //Estimated real proportion of data statistic.
    static int Pop;
    //Population size.
    static int Zscore;
    //Z score, or the amount of standard deviations away from the mean.
    //Z score = sqrt(P(1-p)/N)
    static int stdDev;
    //Standard Deviation, follows the 65, 95, 99 model.  65 percent of all    scores
    //fall in one standard deviation of the mean.  95 percent of all scores fall
    //within two standard deviations of the mean.  99 percent of all scores fall
    //within three standard deviations of the mean.
    static int mean;
    //The average of all the scores of the array.
    static double variance;
    //The average difference between sets of values within the array.
    static String desiredValue = "";
    //This is a string set to the user's command.  Tells whether or not the  value should
    //be lower than, higher than, or not equal to Ho.
    static int[] meanScores = new int[100];
    //Array meant to generate a set of random values within the normal curve of
    //the model, following the 65, 95, 99 rule.
    static Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);
    //Scanner to take in values listed above.  
    static World wor ;
    //Screen which the normal curve is printed on.
    static int size;
    //Variable that measures the size of the array.
    static int temporary;
    //Value Holder for For Loops, While Loops, If Statements, etc.
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
     size = meanScores.length;
     wor = new World(600,600);
     Turtle cursor;
     cursor = new Turtle(300, 500 ,wor);
     runStatisticalMethod();
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(meanScores));
    }
    public static void runStatisticalMethod()
    {
     takeInData();
     calculateStats();
     generateCurve();
     explainSolution(); 

    }
    public static void takeInData()
    {
    System.out.println("Please enter your desired Ho");
    Ho = sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Please enter your desired Ha");
    Ha = sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Please enter your desired population size");
    Pop = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Thanks for entering your data.  Your data will be   compiled below");  

    }
    //Generates a normal curve based on the data from calculateStats() and
    //data entered by the user.
    public static void generateCurve()
    {
     fillRandomArray();
     //Functions as a cursor to draw the normal curve
     for(int x = 0; x < 99; x++)
     {



     }

    }
    //Fills the array meanScores with random integers.
    public static void fillRandomArray()
    {
     double x = 0.0;
     while(x < 100.0)
     {
      (double)randomValue = (Math.random()*100);
      meanScores[x] = randomValue;
      meanScores[x]= meanScores[x]*(stdDev*(Math.random()*3));
      x++;
     }
     assignStdDev();
     for(double x = 0.0; x < 99.0; x++)
     {
      for(double y = 0.0; y < 99.0; y++)
      {
       if(meanScores[y] >= meanScores[y+1])
       {
        double valueHolder1 = meanScores[y];
        double valueHolder2 = meanScores[y+1];
        meanScores[y+1] = valueHolder1;
        meanScores[y] = valueHolder2; 

       }
      }
     }
     System.out.println("The following is a set of 100 random values which follow the normal curve of your hypothesis");
    }
    public static void assignStdDev()
    {
     for(int x = 5; x >=5 && x <=95; x++)
     {
      meanScores[x] = meanScores[x] - (int)(stdDev*Math.random());
     }
     for(int x = 31; x >= 31 && x < 66; x++)
     {
     meanScores[x] = meanScores[x] - (int)(stdDev*Math.random());
     }  
    }
    //Calculates a set of statistics including standard deviation, z-score, mean,
    //interquartile range, probability, and variance.
    public static void calculateStats()
    {
      //Calculates the Mean of the inputted variables and normal curve.
     int sum = 0;
     for(int a : meanScores)
     {
      sum += a;
     }
     mean = sum/size;
     //Calculate the Variance of the inputted variables and normal curve.
     for(int b :meanScores)
     {
      temporary += (b-mean)*(b-mean);
     }
     variance = temporary/size;
     //Calculate the Standard Deviation of the inputted variables and normal curve.
     stdDev = (int)Math.sqrt(variance);
    }
    //This method explains the numbers generated in terms of statistics and analyzes
    //if the hypothesis is probably.  If not, a possible solution is proposed with
    //regards to what should be changed.  Also explains the curve of the graph.
    public static void explainSolution()
    {


    }
  }
```

Comment: please format your code

Comment: remove the bracket around double: `(double)randomValue = (Math.random()*100);` --> `double randomValue = (Math.random()*100);
`

Comment: Why do you use `double` for index `x`?